# Delete or reset Gitlab CI builds

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is it possible to delete old builds in Gitlab CI?
I tested a few things and have now about 20 builds that are useless (most are failed anyway).
It also shows stages that I don't have anymore which kinda clutters the Pipelines page and some of the uploaded artifacts are a bit big.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this, only that disabling CI in the settings doesn't remove the builds.

Using Gitlab 8.10 Community (hosted by Gitlab.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no option in the GUI to completely get rid of a build other than expunge related data from the build. (The erase option in the build)

If you would have a local installation you could modify the database directly but I would advise caution. (I'll put the guide here for completeness sake)

1. Login to the GitLab database. If you use the default PostgreSQL :

   ```
   sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production
   ```
2. Check if there is a table `ci_builds`. For pSQL: `\dt`
3. Delete the builds with normal SQL. For example: `DELETE FROM ci_builds WHERE id = 2`
4. (Optional) If you want to cleanup a list of commits which triggered a build you need to midify the table `ci_commits`.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! Do you happen do know where I could make a feature request? on the Gitlab repo maybe?

Comment: @JohannesBildstein [This](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/2560) Merge Request introduced the ability to erase a build. If you want to make a feature proposal you would need to open a issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues) an tag it appropriately.

Comment: Awesome, thank you again! With the erase button I was able to remove the big artifacts now and I realized that in each Pipeline page it only shows the build stages of the builds that are visible. So after a few builds my clutter problem will be gone as well.

Comment: Thanks  and ie: `delete  from ci_builds where project_id = 8 and created_at < now() -  interval '5 days' `

Comment: This is a terrible idea. A tool's database is almost never public API. It can change at any time.

GitLab HAS provided public API for working with Jobs. It's [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#erase-a-job). Use that.

Comment: The question remains why you want to delete, suggesting to delete from database definitely will leave build artifacts and build logs around. Those are stored on disk or in s3. Not a recommended way to clean up to free some space. Leaving things orphaned is bad idea in any case.